# Setting max width for inline images breaks container width

Tags: html, css

Setting `max-width` style value for images inside carousel breaks width of the container. This happens even though max-width value would not affect actual width of the images. I cannot figure out why this happens.

I created a JSFiddle about this because I'm unable to explain this issue otherwise: https://jsfiddle.net/atmp9ymr/1/

So I'm basically asking why this happens? Is there a way to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

--

Edit. I try to explain the issue here:

So I have images inline within a container. Container forces items to be inline by using `white-space: nowrap` and images have `inline-block` and display style. This container does have position set to absolute if that matters. Everything is fine currently. Container which holds images has correct width (according to images inside). Now if I set `max-width: 100%` for images, container width is broken. Even if image size does not change, width is not anymore correct. I cannot find a logic for that.

Please check the jsfiddle for better explanation.

Comment: does adding overflow: hidden to the containers class solve your problem?

Comment: @Barry_127 Thanks for a suggestion. It seems to have no effect unfortunately. :(

Comment: @K.Daniek if you check fiddle I think you will understand. Sorry for lack of explaining on description, but I have no idea how to explain this in words. :( It's very specific issue.

Comment: in both cases the #container has 500px for me... 1050 is the sum of images

Comment: `#container` always has the same width. Only the width of `#inner` is changing.

Comment: @CleitonSouza Sorry for confusing explanation. You are right. So width of the #container is always 500. But width of the #inner changes and I cannot find out why.

Comment: Does setting width:100% on .item help? :)

Comment: You could simply remove `position: relative;` from your `#container` and remove `top: 0;` from your `#inner` as a workaround.

Comment: @Huelfe Thanks but this does not seem to fix the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/atmp9ymr/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max-Width of the images relates to the containing element.

So max-width: 100% on the image means "use 100% of ".item". .item is not further restricted and by using position:absolute on #inner, you have set this element to 100% (of viewport).

Try adding "border: 1px solid red" to #inner and #container to see, where the elements are drawn.

As long as there is not speciefied what has to happen, wenn sizes exeed the container, this will happen.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for explanation. But can you explain why images are not screwed up when setting max-width to 100%? I know setting max-width to 100% here is not very useful, but If you check this: https://jsfiddle.net/atmp9ymr/4/ you'll see that images seem to have correct size.

Comment: I actually think I an live with this answer. Setting max-width to 100% here does not make sense here and I need to remove that and refactor my code so I don't have to set that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firefox, Opera and Chrome have a workaround for this.

```
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex; /* add display flex */
}

.item {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: -moz-max-content; /* this will stretch the items to maximum width */
  width: -webkit-max-content; /* this will stretch the items to maximum width */
  width: max-content; /* for future */
}
```

Have a look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atmp9ymr/8/).

Comment: For my specific case this won't work, since I have to support IE11, but thanks! That's really nice!

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is the mixing of percentage widths with inferred (auto) widths, and combining this with absolute positioning.

`max-width:100%` means the browser has to translate a percentage value into something absolute. This may yield unexpected results if ancestors have `width:auto` (which by the way is the default), and are absolutely positioned.

In such cases, percentage values make little sense, and 100% might just as well be interpreted as **100% *of the element itself*** – not 100% of the parent/ancestor.

If you want to use percentage values here, you should make sure that the ancestors' widths are clearly set (to something other than `auto`). However, this might prevent the `#inner` wrapper from dynamically adjusting its width to wrap all its `.item` children.

In the end, the easy/ugly solution may be the best: [Set the `max-width` to an absolute value](https://jsfiddle.net/wygaskh8/). (For example the pixel width of `#container`.)

PS: I created [a variation of your case](http://jsfiddle.net/c3zgrLwL/). Maybe you'll find it useful.